# Fetching a set of images in Servlet and send them to my Android app

Tags: image, google-app-engine, http, url, servlets

I am following [this](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/java/serving_dynamic_images) tutorial where it's explained how to store images into a Datastore by declaring the image as a `Blob` object. That's fine, the problem is that in the example the images are fetched this way:

```
public class StoreMovieServlet extends HttpServlet {
@Override
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
        throws IOException {
    URLFetchService fetchService = URLFetchServiceFactory.getURLFetchService();
    // Fetch the image at the location given by the url query string parameter
    HTTPResponse fetchResponse = fetchService.fetch(new URL(req.getParameter("url")));

    String fetchResponseContentType = null;
    for (HTTPHeader header : fetchResponse.getHeaders()) {
        // For each request header, check whether the name equals
        // "Content-Type"; if so, store the value of this header
        // in a member variable
        if (header.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("content-type")) {
            fetchResponseContentType = header.getValue();
            break;
        }
    }
    if (fetchResponseContentType != null) {
        // Create a new Movie instance
        Movie movie = new Movie();
        movie.setTitle(req.getParameter("title"));
        movie.setImageType(fetchResponseContentType);

        // Set the movie's promotional image by passing in the bytes pulled
        // from the image fetched via the URL Fetch service
        movie.setImage(fetchResponse.getContent());

        PersistenceManager pm = PMF.get().getPersistenceManager();
        try {
            // Store the image in App Engine's datastore
            pm.makePersistent(movie);
        } finally {
            pm.close();
        }
    }
}
}
```

and I don't have an `url` from where to fetch the images.
Instead, I'd like to store them somewhere in my `Servlet` and then from there to store them into the Datastore.

Hence, how can I fetch some images stored locally in my Servlet, instead of getting them from an external url?

In other words, where should I position the images that I want to serve?

> **UPDATE**
>
> As suggested by @Nick, I realized that the the tutorial in question isn't the good solution to my needs. Thus I've changed it all over again and did so, within the `doPost` method of my `Servlet`:

```
InputStream s = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("http://cardimgs.org/imgs/cardbackground1.jpg");

    Movie movie = new Movie();
    try {
        byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(s);
        movie.setImage(bytes);

    }catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    PersistenceManager pm = PMF.get().getPersistenceManager();
    try {
        // Store the image in App Engine's datastore
        pm.makePersistent(movie);
    } finally {
        pm.close();
    }
```

`Movie` class:
[link](http://pastie.org/private/75ufhdfyadqey1c7ubt3w),

and my `appengine-web.xml`:
[link 1](http://pastie.org/private/7rpniccy721a3ypjnseoq)

where I try to define my static files. The problem is, though, that with the code above the `InputStream` appears to be `null` and returns a `NullPointerException`.
Here is how I stored my images in the Servlet:

[link 2](http://postimg.org/image/obsolifx7/)

How can I successfully access my static files?

> **UPDATE 2**
>
> I was able to load images by changing this:

```
InputStream s = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("http://cardimgs.org/imgs/cardbackground1.jpg");
```

to this:

```
InputStream s = getServletContext().getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/imgs/cardbackground1.jpg");
```

no need to add the path to the folder with the attribute `<include>` in the `appengine-web.xml` file.

Comment: there is no such thing as storing in a servlet. wouldnt make sense in appengine as the instance can change

Comment: then where should I position the images that I want to serve?

Comment: datastore or more appropiately gce

Comment: of course, but in order to store the images in the datastore you need to fetch them from somewhere. The question is: from where?

Comment: you mean they are part of your appengine resources? if so they have a url. of course if you already have them as resource i see no point in storing elsewhere. thats why i dont understand the Q

Comment: let's say my images are under `backend>src>main>images`, then what is this url?

Comment: you need to put them somewhere accessible from outside ie where you would put images to display on a web page.

Comment: but i still dont get your Q. if you already have them, why duplicate them elsewhere. just store their url in datastore.

Comment: because "I have them" means that they are in my laptop but I want to serve them to new users. The reason is because I think that in order to convert an images into a `Blob`, you first need to have access to the image.
My idea is, if this makes any sense, to create a folder containing the images, and when a new image is added this must be converted to `Blob`, and then stored into the Datastore.

Comment: arquitexturally doesnt make sense unless you are doing this  from the development gae

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This tutorial at a cursory glance is not a good way of dealing with this type of content. It looked to be an old tutorial.

To store an image in gae you should use the imageservice. It will handle all the basics for you and give you a URL to render the content on a webpage. It can also handle dynamic resizing and cropping, as well as serve it through googles infrastructure.

To address your surface question, to load a file from your Java project, you use the class loader.

```
this.class.getClassloader().getResourceAsStream("image/resource.jpg")
```

However, you can also serve static resources from your war directly on GAE, which again will be managed by google's infrastructure and is a preferred approach.
This is configured in the appengine-web.xml file. 
Based on your description, I think this is what you should do.

Comment: ok thank you... now that I am able to access the images and then store them into a Movie object, do you think I should also make them persistent and then send them back to the app, or I should directly send them to the app instead?

Comment: You can serve any content in your war that isn't in the WEB-INF folder as a web asset. You don't need to to save the data in the datastore. This is not always appropriate (for example if you want to index all of imdb, that would be a bad approach). In your case, just put the image in your war, say in images/image-1.jpg then you can serve it using http://myapp.appspot.com/images/image-1.jpg. If you take this approach, that's all you need to save in your movie object, the URL, not the full byte[]

Comment: Ok, but I don't want to display the images in a Web browser, I want to send them to my app. So how do I send them to my android app?

Comment: First step - include that in your SO question initially. Second step - send the URL to your android app and get them to fetch it. Alternatively as you've done you can save it and send the byte stream, but the web is great at serving content - content type, optimisation of  connections, caching, edge caching, etag) - you won't do any of that. Your hand rolled solution will probably be suboptimal. Appengine is all about leaning on the strengths of the environment, not programming your way around the basics.

Comment: I would say if the total of the images is under 10mb, include it in your war for simplicity. If it's over 10mb, save them into the image service using a file upload servlet, and serve those urls. Either way, I wouldn't send image data as base64 encoded data in Json to android unless they're tiny thumbnails.